# Accessing a Dependency Property in Custom Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, controltemplate

I need some help with dependency properties.  Hi I want to access two properties that are defined in a Control Template, CheckedText and UncheckedText:

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="110" />
    <Setter Property="packages:Variables.X" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF939393" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Grid x:Name="Container">

                        ...

                        <Border Height="{Binding Height,
                                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding styles:ToggleCheckBox.CheckedBackground}">
                            <Border.Width>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{arithmeticConverter:ArithmeticConverter}" ConverterParameter="x-y">
                                    <Binding Path="Width" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                                    <Binding Path="(styles:ToggleCheckBox.ToggleWidth)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Border.Width>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                       FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                       FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding styles:ToggleCheckBox.CheckedForeground}"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding styles:ToggleCheckBox.**CheckedText**}" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border Width="{Binding Width,
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                Converter={arithmeticConverter:ArithmeticConverter},
                                                ConverterParameter=x-20}"
                                Height="{Binding Height,
                                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding styles:ToggleCheckBox.UncheckedBackground}">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                       FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                       FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding styles:ToggleCheckBox.UncheckedForeground}"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding styles:ToggleCheckBox.**UncheckedText**}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <Border Background="Transparent"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="1" />
                </Grid>
```

And here is the definition of the dependency properties in the ToggleCheckBox:

```
public class ToggleCheckBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CheckedText", typeof(string), typeof(ToggleCheckBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("ON"));
    public static void SetCheckedText(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(CheckedTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetCheckedText(UIElement element)
    {
        return (String)element.GetValue(CheckedTextProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UncheckedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UncheckedText", typeof(string), typeof(ToggleCheckBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("OFF"));

    public static void SetUncheckedText(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(UncheckedTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetUncheckedText(UIElement element)
    {
        return (String)element.GetValue(UncheckedTextProperty);
    }
}
```

And in the usage in my view:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="IsDataStoreLocal"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Style="{StaticResource ToggleCheckBoxStyle}" 
          CheckedText="YES" 
          UnCheckedText="NO"/>
```

What I would like to do is something like the above.  Of course the properties are not recognized, probably because I have only a style, not a control.  How can I change the Checked and UncheckedText values in a new checkbox using this style?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks, Will

I have looked at similar questions, but cannot find one that matches what I am trying to do.

Comment: do you mean that properties are not recognized in usage `<CheckBox CheckedText="YES"/>` or in template?

Comment: In the usage.  I will edit the post.  Thank you.

Comment: try to use it with declaring type `<CheckBox styles:ToggleCheckBox.CheckedText="YES"/>` like other attached properties (e.g `Grid.Column`).

Comment: Are you having separate `usercontrol` for `ToggleCheckBox`? or you just applying the `Style` for default `CheckBox`? or having `AttahcedProperty`?

Comment: @ASh, that works!  Didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @Gopichandar, I am applying the Style to a default Checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to set an **attached property** value on a target element (checkBox), use the following syntax:

```
namespacePrefix:ownerTypeName.propertyName
```

in case of your custom property:

```
<CheckBox styles:ToggleCheckBox.CheckedText="YES"/>
```